# Dependency resolution error when updating Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am running `yum update` on RHEL6 Workstation as I have always done in the past but it fails:

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libipa_hbac which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libipa_hbac of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libipa_hbac.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libipa_hbac installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libipa_hbac installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libipa_hbac-1.12.4-47.el6_7.7.i686 != libipa_hbac-1.12.4-47.el6_7.8.x86_64
```

I follow suggestion number 1 and it displays the following:

```
# yum update --exclude libipa_hbac.i686
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-573.12.1.el6 will be erased
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-573.12.1.el6 will be erased
---> Package libipa_hbac.x86_64 0:1.12.4-47.el6_7.7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libipa_hbac = 1.12.4-47.el6_7.7 for package: libipa_hbac-python-1.12.4-47.el6_7.7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libipa_hbac-python-1.12.4-47.el6_7.7.x86_64 (@rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
           Requires: libipa_hbac = 1.12.4-47.el6_7.7
           Removing: libipa_hbac-1.12.4-47.el6_7.7.x86_64 (@rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.12.4-47.el6_7.7
           Updated By: libipa_hbac-1.12.4-47.el6_7.8.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.12.4-47.el6_7.8
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.5.1-66.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.5.1-66.el6
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.5.1-66.el6_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.5.1-66.el6_2.1
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.5.1-66.el6_2.3.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.5.1-66.el6_2.3
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.8.0-32.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.8.0-32.el6
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-82.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-82.el6
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-82.4.el6_4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-82.4.el6_4
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-82.7.el6_4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-82.7.el6_4
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-82.10.el6_4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-82.10.el6_4
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-82.11.el6_4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-82.11.el6_4
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-129.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-129.el6
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.9.2-129.el6_5.4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.9.2-129.el6_5.4
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.11.6-30.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.11.6-30.el6
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.11.6-30.el6_6.3.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.11.6-30.el6_6.3
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.11.6-30.el6_6.4
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.12.4-47.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.12.4-47.el6
           Available: libipa_hbac-1.12.4-47.el6_7.4.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               libipa_hbac = 1.12.4-47.el6_7.4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any idea why `yum update` stopped working all of a sudden and how to fix that?

Comment: I think the problem is on Redhat's side: there are packages that require libipa_hbac 1.12.4-47.el6_7.7, but the latest available is 1.12.4-47.el6_7.*8*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libipa_hbac-python is now located in the rhel-6-workstation-optional-rpms channel. If you enable that repo everything should update just fine.